# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'training'

Tags: google-colaboratory, training-data, amazon-sagemaker-studio, stylegan

Trying to train a new dataset from StyleGAN2 using stylegan2-ADA-pytorch using SageMaker Studio.

On the attempt to execute train.py, several imports fail. So I moved them out of train.py to call direct.

import os

import click
import torch
import json
import tempfile
import training

Error=

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 10
8 import json
9 import tempfile
---> 10 import training
12 from training import training_loop
13 from metrics import metric_main

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'training'

Training module is there. Was not an issue on Colab.

click and torch were also issues, but moving them out of train.py worked. Thoughts?

Comment: Could you share some more information here, are you utilizing a training job or running training on the Studio Instance?